# where are these duplicated GUI elements coming from?

Tags: c, winapi

I recently attempted to code a GUI in a DLL using .rc files, but unfortunately have ran into

a few problems. Here is a screenshot of the GUI:

[image]

As you can see, the text "Main Window Found? No" has been duplicated (which I did not do),

also the box has also been duplicated (which I also did not do.)

This is the code I use to generate the Dialog:

```
DWORD WINAPI MainWin (HMODULE hMod)
{
    DialogBox (hMod, MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, (DLGPROC)EventHandler); 
    ExitThread (0);
    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EventHandler (HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        ControlHwnd = hDlg;

        case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case IDC_CHECKBOX1:
                Test = !Test;
                CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&TestFunc,NULL,0,NULL);
                Beep (500,500); 
                break;
        }
        break; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that "please help", especially when suffixed with exclamation marks, is very inappropriate in a question title - please edit your question and use a meaningful title.

Comment: Please add the code where you call into your "MainWin" function. Are you by any chance call this from DllMain?

Comment: Who calls `MainWin()`, and more importantly, how many times is it called?

Comment: It would be also nice if you could provide the `.rc` file too.

Answer (score 2):

```
DialogBox (..., (DLGPROC)EventHandler);
```

Well, you got the compiler to shut-up and tell you that you are doing something wrong.  You invoked "god-mode" with that cast.  Even God uses *break* in a switch statement though.  And pays attention to the rules of the dialog callback procedure, well explained in the [oracle of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645469%28VS.85%29.aspx).

There are lots of class libraries around that help you avoid falling into these kind of traps.  Qt, MFC, Winforms, WPF, etcetera.  You can invoke god-mode after you read Petzold and understood everything.